# How to use window.open when onClick is also a javascript event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window.open, new-window

I want to make this Javascript open a new window. I don't know where to put the `window.open` as it takes up the [www.cuteredshoes.com](http://www.cuteredshoes.com) browser window instead. I want to open both storefronts in separate windows (or tabs).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stephen-paul-west.artistwebsites.com/slideshowmouseover.php?id=1234011&memberidtype=artistid&memberid=123401&width=250px&height=250px'></script>
<img id='faaslideshowimage[1234011]' onClick='javascript: mouseclick1234011(event);' onMouseOver='javascript: mouseover1234011();' onMouseOut='javascript: mouseout1234011();'src='http://fineartamerica.com/Blank.jpg' style='width: 250px; height: 250px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 1px solid #666666; cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' alt='Art Prints' title='Art Prints'
```

Comment: New guy. I just figured out how to add the code. Thanks Tim.